# Add to data from getJSON

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

I am calling $.getJSON on a url which containts calendar events in the following format.

```
[{"guid":"53c2d70ae6014","date":"1408161600000","type":"event","title":"Weekend Classes Begin","description":"","url":"" },
 {"guid":"53c2d70ae601c","date":"1408248000000","type":"event","title":"Freshman Orientation","description":"","url":"" },
 {"guid":"53c2d70ae6022","date":"1408334400000","type":"event","title":"Freshman Orientation","description":"","url":"" }]
```

It gets the JSON and puts it into an array and when I use `alert(data);` it shows up as

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]...
```

I want to be able to add an one or more events to the `data` I receive from the `$.getJSON` call.

```
$.getJSON(eventsOpts.eventsjson + "?limit="+limit+"&year="+year+"&month="+month+"&day="+day, function(data) {
            if(localStorage.getItem('agenda') === null)
            {

            }
            else
            {
            var json = localStorage.getItem('agenda');
            var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(json);

            data.push(json);
            alert(data);
            }

            flags.eventsJson = data; // save data to future filters
            getEventsData(flags.eventsJson, limit, year, month, day, direction);
        }).error(function() {
            showError("error no internet connection.");
        });
```

The json I want to append is `{"guid":"53c2e0a3d0680","date":"1418922000000","type":"event","title":"Fall 2014 Graduation","description":"","url":"" }`

What I get is

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],{"guid":"53c2e0a3d0680","date":"1418922000000","type":"event","title":"Fall 2014 Graduation","description":"","url":"" }
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: show how you're appending, looks like a string and not an object.

Comment: Don't use `alert()` to inspect variables. As you can see, it's not very useful. Use the browser console instead (e.g. `console.log()`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to re-parse the object from `localStorage` then push:

```
var json = localStorage.getItem('agenda'),
    myObj = JSON.parse(json);

data.push(myObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

var `json` in your example is a string. pass it to `JSON.parse()` that converst JSON strings to JavaScript Objects.